# Finding PDF of a converted random process

Tags: stochastic-processes, density-function

Let $s(t)$ be a periodic triangle wave as illustrated in the accompanying
figure. Suppose a random process is created according to $X(t) = s(t − T)$,
where $T$ is a random variable uniformly distributed over $(0, 1)$.

[image: s(t) graph]

And I need to find the probability density function of this new $X(t)$...

So I thought like this. $s(t)$ got a period of $1$. So $X(t)$ can be any waveform created by shifting $s(t)$ within it's period time frame. Since $T$ is random within the $s(t)$'s period, is it fine to get the PDF from $s(t)$ directly by integrating it like this?

$$f_X(x) = \int\limits_{0}^{x}s(t)dt$$

Comment: No; no it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is that $s(t-T)$ and $s(T)$ have identical distributions due to periodicity and symmetry.   This is okay.   However that then gives you:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X(t)\leq x) ~=&~ \mathsf P(s(t-T)\leq x) \\[1ex] ~=&~ \mathsf P(s(T)\leq x)\\[1ex] ~=&~ \int_{-1}^x f_{s(T)}(z)\operatorname d z~\mathbf 1_{x\in(-1;1)}+\mathbf 1_{x\in[1;\infty)}\end{align}$$

Then by taking derivatives: $~f_{X(t)}(x) = f_{s(T)}(x)~$  (... which we could have said directly).

In short: What you need to determine is, if $T$ is uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$, then what distribution does $s(T)$ have?   (Hence what is its probability density function?)

---

> The support of $X(t)$ is $(-1;1)$ and the distribution is *uniform* because ... the relation between $T$ and $s(T)$ is *linear* in *either* of two parts of the support of $T$, and *both* of these intervals are folded *onto* the support of $s(T)$ (a surjective mapping).   **tl/dr:** The density function is $f_X(x) = \tfrac 12 \mathbf 1_{x\in(-1;1)}$

Comment: Why did you consider a $(-1,1)$ range for $x$? :) Can't we take the period as $(0, 1)$?

Comment: @Blogger $T\in (0;1)$ but $s(T)\in(-1;1)$ and so is $X(t)$ ( $:=s(t-T)$ ).

Comment: Ahh now I get it! I was looking at the $t$ axis all this time. So $s(T)$ is distributed over $(-1,1)$ means $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @Blogger Almost there.  The support of $X(t)$ is $(-1;1)$ and the distribution is uniform because ... the relation between $T$ and $s(T)$ is *linear* in *either* of two parts of the support of $T$, and *both* of these intervals are folded *onto* the support of $s(T)$ (a surjective mapping).  (**tl/dr:** Yes.)

Comment: Now it's clear to me! :) Let's say $s(t)$ was a cosine function. Still the pdf of $X(t)$ will be $\frac{1}{2}$ in the region of $(-1,1)$ right? Assume T is distributed uniformly over $(0, 2\pi)$

Comment: @Blogger, Oh, no.  *Non-linearity* complicates matters; muchly.  You would have to use a *change of variables transformation* that accounts for any folding.  In that case: $$\begin{align}f_X(x) =&~  f_T(\arccos(x)) \lvert\frac{\mathrm d \arccos(x) }{\mathrm d x}\rvert + f_T(2\pi-\arccos(x)) \lvert\frac{\mathrm d 2\pi-\arccos(x) }{\mathrm d x}\rvert \\[1ex] =&~ \frac 1 {\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathbf 1_{x\in(-1;1)}\end{align}$$

Comment: I'll try to absorb this a little more! Thanks @Graham for the help! It was a great thing!